# maxlength on field not working with Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I have a field with a maxlength of 6, but somehow the following way of entering data results in 7 chars being allowed:

```
<input type="text" name="myName" maxlength="6" ng-model="myModel">
```

this is the test bit:

```
input('myModel').enter('1111117');
expect(input('myModel').val()).toBe(111111);
```

and this is the result

```
expected 111111 but was "1111117"
```

I suppose this has to do with the model being used instead of the real field, but how would I test this then in Karma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused because `maxlength` only limits the input from the user, and not the actual value of the input. For example, if you try to use jQuery's `val()` on your input, it would accept any length of the value.

I tried to simulate input in more sophisticated ways, like triggering keyboard events or [third party tools](https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype), but with no success. It looks like any programmatic way to change the input's value, is not limited by `maxlength`.

Comment: I tried the triggering of keyboard events to to no avail, so will consider this unsolvable. We're using Protractor more and more, so hopefully this won't be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this may be helpful to someone with the same problem.

In my case I just checked the the value length of the input manually, in the function used to set the input value:

```
function insertKey(input: HTMLInputElement, key: string) {
  input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: key}));
  if (input.value.length < input.maxLength) {
    input.value += key;
    input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('change', null));
  }
  input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {key: key}));
}
```